# How can I disable the rounded display corners Gala plugin?

Tags: release-freya, gala, display

At all 4 corners of my screen there are rounded corners, but I want to use my screen normally and use all pixels I have. Is there any way to configure this?

Answer (score 8):

This was a design decision made by the developers for Freya. There are some settings for Gala (the window manager in elementary OS) that control the corner masking. You can install *dconf-editor* (`sudo apt-get install dconf-editor`) to change the settings via a GUI, or use the built-in *gsettings* command from a terminal. You need to set the *enable* property to **false** in the *org.pantheon.desktop.gala.mask-corners* schema. The *gsettings* command for this is:

```
gsettings set org.pantheon.desktop.gala.mask-corners enable false
```

You can later reset to default with:

```
gsettings reset org.pantheon.desktop.gala.mask-corners enable
```