# Small spec in top left of screen - Driver issue

Tags: graphic-drivers

I have a small black screen in the top left of my screen when using proprietary NVIDIA driver (shown in screenshots below).

I tried changing the driver after I noticed this and that fixed it (but the other driver had a different bug).

I know this isn't part of my laptop since it only exists when using Elementary OS, if I restart it doesn't show for a while, and the other driver had it go away.

[image: this spec]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this wasn't just in the top left corner, but all four corners. After I noticed, I found out that this issue occurs due to the rounded edges Elementary OS has.

Therefore, I was able to go into gedit and change the corners to not be rounded.

`gsettings set org.pantheon.desktop.gala.mask-corners enable false`

([How can I disable the rounded display corners Gala plugin?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/1360/how-can-i-disable-the-rounded-display-corners-gala-plugin))